# Is there a way to prevent a content add-in from getting focus when in present mode?

Tags: powerpoint, office-js, office-addins, powerpoint-addins, powerpoint-web-addins

I'm using the office.js (javascript) and powerpoint api and I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent the content add-in element from getting focused while presenting?

While presenting a slide containing my content add-in, a mouse click inside the content add-in will prevent me from going to the next slide before I click outside the add-in again. Since the web page inside the content add-in is in no need of focus, I would like the mouse click to act as "normal" and take me to the next slide. Is this possible?

I'm expecting there to be some kind of method in the office.js or PowerPoint API to prevent this, or the possibility to use javascript/typescript or maybe CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The Office JavaScript API doesn't provide any property or method for that.

You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team goes through the planning process.